# Older movie/show about humans on derelict alien warship which refuels by passing through a star

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I am trying to find the title to a show (or movie?) from several years ago.

The basic premise was a small group of people who ended up in deep space on a large alien warship that was heavily damaged, derelict and just flying on auto.

A memorable portion that may help you to help me was when the ship flew itself into a star to refuel.  That had the humans quite distressed.

Comment: Hi there! Roughly how long ago is "several years ago"? Five years, fifty?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I saw it 5+/- years ago at a friend's place on *gasp* vhs tape but it was NOT new at that time.  It could be 10 or less.  I know, quite vague.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: Nice to know! You can [edit] that information in your post, as well as any other memory [this guide on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) might remind you of. :)

Comment: Jenayah, I feel so silly after reviewing your link regarding asking story-id questions.  I barely met a couple of those gates.  It's purely amazing my question was answered so fast given so little initial data was provided.  Should the need arise, I'll be sure to include much more information.  Thank you again.

Comment: There's absolutely no worry! Welcome to the site, and hope you stick around! Who knows, maybe you can take a look at [these unanswered story-ids](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) and provide an answer :)

Comment: My brain refuses to believe that SGU and VHS existed at the same time. It's still the "new one" as far as I'm concerned!

Comment: Just for the record. This sounds a lot like the book "Rendezvous With Rama" by Arthur C Clark.

Comment: @jared.nesbit I was gonna mention Rama too, but I know it couldn't be the answer since it's not a movie.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd suggest that this is *Stargate: Universe*, the starship does this on a couple of occasions

> Destiny reactors are fueled by absorbing and storing stellar material through a series of ram scoops on the underside of each wing. To accomplish this, Destiny dives into the photosphere of a star, absorbing material during its fly-through. The shields allow matter to pass through for the ram scoops to collect while keeping the ship completely protected from the intense conditions. However, large, hot stars (such as Blue giants) are more than the Destiny's protective capabilities can fully handle. Destiny can still use these stars to recharge though not without incurring some degree of damage and putting great strain on its shields. The ship will perform this recharging process automatically whenever power levels drop below a certain point.
>
> [Wikia](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Destiny)

Comment: Thank you all. This has been driving me mad for quite a while.  Great community you guys have created.  I hope that I can be if similar service to someone else.  Thank you again.

Comment: I loved this show. Too bad it was cancelled. I was coming off of BSG show completion withdrawal, and was looking for that next awesome SF show to get hooked on and SGU did the trick for me.......then SciFi pulls the plug after two seasons. :(

Answer (score 22):

Not much to go on, but [Stargate: Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Universe) fits the few details. Its last episode aired 8 years ago, it has the group of people stranded on the spaceship flying on auto and the ship does refuel in a sun.

See if this looks familiar:

Comment: Oh my Gosh!  That's it!  I can now go find purchase options.  Thank you so very much.  Once I figure out how to add positive remarks on my question resolution folks I will do so.  Again, Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure it's on one of the streaming services (prime, netflix, etc)

Comment: @DanMill Not sure if it's already on your radar or not, but you may also be interested in looking at Stargate: SG-1 and Stargate Atlantis (but particularly SG-1.)  While SGU *is* a self-contained show in its own right and most things should be easily understandable on their own, this show is the second spin-off of SG-1 and built on top of the legacy and continuity of those previous shows.  There's a lot of backstory about the Ancients, for example, that gets glossed over or only mentioned briefly, but the earlier shows go into more detail about.

Comment: 8 years? That can't be right... I feel old now.

Comment: Harabeck, I feel you there!

Comment: Steve-O, Thank you.  I'll take a gander.  Who knows, it could make the bingeable list.

Comment: xQbert, you are quite right!  It's on Prime.  My weekend is now booked up solid.  Thank you.

Comment: @Steve-O And SG-1 is itself a spin-off of the Stargate movie.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like a "Dünyayı Kurtatan Adam", that is a good movie.

Comment: Hi there. Could you edit your post to explain how that matches, such as providing a summary, quotes or clips? :)

Comment: Well it seems like movie was found, so I believe I will delete this one.

Comment: No need to delete it, similar matches for answers are fine.

Comment: Similar match are fine. Peoples may have a similar question end up here and discover that Stargate was not what they were looking for. But please do add detail. make this an answer. For now it's more a comment. It's an infamous B-movie. What point in the question does it match?